# Date column is returning pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
def get_sample(df):
    sample_y = df[df["Date"] > earliest_date].sample()
    date = sample_y["Date"]
    print(type(date))
    print(date)
```

I want to randomly sample a row from a df, then get the date of that random row I've sampled.

I would expect `sample_y["Date"]` to return something of a date time type and just be the date from that row, however my print statements return:

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

417061   2014-11-17

Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

I am unable to extract the meaningful date out of `date` with this data type, it's pair with this ID I don't want.

How can I get a date value from `sample_y["Date"]`?

Comment: `sample()` returns a series or dataframe, since you can request more than one items.

Comment: You access the data in the dataframe the same way as any other df.

Comment: `sample_y` in this work is a dataframe, not a series. I did check for this but forgot to mention, sorry.

Comment: as `sample_y` if a dataframe, `sample_y["Date"]` is the `Date` column as a series. If you want a specific row you should indicate that, eg. `sample_y["Date"][0]`, where `[0]` represents the first row.

Comment: That returns a KeyError for me.